# Decomposing large symmetric banded sparse matrices

Tags: matrices, sparse-matrices

I'm investigating 3D image deblurring and one of the approaches I'm interested in is applying spatial regularisation.  To do this I have generated a matrix $A$ which encodes the 6-connectivity of each image voxel (i.e. the adjacent voxels in $x$,$y$, and $z$ planes).  For the specific images I am working with this results in a large (5242880x5242880), sparse, symmetric, banded, matrix with $1$s on the first, 512-nd and 262144-th super- and sub- diagonals.  All other entries are $0$.

To compute the regularised solution I need to obtain the inverse of $A$.  It seems intuitive that it should be possible to factorise or otherwise easily decompose this highly structured binary matrix into smaller matrices to make this problem more tractable?

Thanks

Comment: In case of low attention here, worth asking over at [scicomp.SE](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

One efficient method (using [Hessenberg matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix)) is described here: [The inverse of banded matrices](http://faculty.nps.edu/pstanica/research/2013JCAM_BandedMatr.pdf) (2013).

> Let $B_{r,n}$ ($1 \leq r \leq n$) be an $n \times n$ matrix of entries
>   $\{a_{ij}\}$, $−r \leq i \leq r$, $1 \leq j \leq r$, with the
>   remaining un-indexed entries all zeros. In this paper we give the LU
>   factorization and the inverse of the matrix $B_{r,n}$, using a method 
>   based on Hessenberg submatrices associated to $B_{r,n}$.